# Problem with recurrence relation splitting into two.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Soo I have been working on this problem and I am unsure how to do this and what will come out.I have:
$a_n=a_{n-1}+(n+2)b_{n-1}$
  $b_n=b_{n-1}+a_{n-1}(n+2)$ 
I need to find $a_n$ and $b_n$ separately in in a for which contains only n-s since I will need to combine them as $a_n/b_n$.(Because the first part was actually $c_n$=$c_{n-1}$+(n+2)/1+$c_{n-1}$(n +2).I had found by induction that is always a rational number and I had to split $c_n$ into two recurrence relations the top part being $a_n$ and the bottom $b_n$.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but why not try $c_n=a_n+b_n$ ?

Comment: $c_n=(n+3)c_{n-1}$ then $n\geq 1, c_n=\prod\limits_{1\leq k\leq n} (3+k)c_0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $c_n=a_n+b_n$ and $d_n=a_n-b_n$. Then it satisfies

$$
c_{n}=c_{n-1}+\left(n+2\right)c_{n-1}=\left(n+3\right)c_{n-1} \text{ and } d_{n}=d_{n-1}-\left(n+2\right)d_{n-1}=-\left(n+1\right)d_{n-1}
$$

You can find $c_n$ and $d_n$ explicitly and conclude about $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Comment: (+1) I was just about to post a very similar solution. This seems the way to go.

Comment: I think this should work out.Thanks for the help :)